# Why am I getting Lapack routine dgesv system is exactly singular error?

Tags: r, model, conditional-statements, mlogit

I am trying to run a logistic regression with the data structure as follows *(The original data has **10 columns** and **296 rows** in the format as shown in the example)*:

```
Food  d.bri  d.cau  d.bre  d.pea  FA     FC     Delay   Agg     Rej
F1    1      0      0      0      5.00   3.00   2.00    3.00    0.00
F2    0      1      0      0      4.00   4.00   3.00    5.00    0.00
F3    0      0      1      0      3.00   5.00   5.00    7.00    0.00
F4    0      0      0      1      2.00   2.00   4.00    7.00    0.00
F1    1      0      0      0      5.00   5.00   5.00    7.00    0.00
F3    0      0      1      0      4.00   4.00   4.00    7.00    0.00
F2    0      1      0      0      3.00   3.00   5.00    7.00    0.00
F4    0      0      0      1      2.00   2.00   5.00    7.00    0.00
```

Transformation of the data has been done with

```
l.data = mlogit.data(DATA, choice = 'Food', shape = 'wide')
```

With the following *multinomial* code, I get the result as expected.

`FC_F1 = mlogit(Food ~ 1 | FC, data = l.data, reflevel = 'F1')`

However, on trying to run a *conditional* model, I get the following error

`Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0`

The code I am using is

```
c.logit_F1 = mlogit(Food ~ Agg+Delay|FC, data = l.data, reflevel = 'F1')
```

I am unsure as to what is causing the problem.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible check out [ask] and [mre]. You could add a minimal set of your data with `dput(DATA)` or `DATA <-  data.frame(...)` where ... are the elements of your data frame;  only including the variables and enough rows to reproduce the issues which your question addresses.

Comment: That's an issue with your data. The model might be too complex for your data.